# Illegal url for new iframe

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

i want to use google sign in button for my firebase project;but when i push the google sign in button i get this error:

**Uncaught Error: Illegal url for new iframe**

MY code is here :

TY FOR YOUR HELP.

```js
firebase.initializeApp({
 apiKey: '***',
 authDomain: 'https://***.firebaseapp.com',
 projectId: '***'
});


var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
var uiConfig = {
  callbacks: {
    signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function(authResult, redirectUrl) {

      return true;
    },
    uiShown: function() {

      document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
    }
  },

  signInFlow: 'popup',
  signInSuccessUrl: 'https://***.web.app/',
  signInOptions: [

    firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID

  ],
  // Terms of service url.
  tosUrl: 'https://***.web.app/',
  // Privacy policy url.
  privacyPolicyUrl: 'https://***.web.app/'
};



ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
```

```html
 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.4.0/firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.8.0/firebase-ui-auth.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.8.0/firebase-ui-auth.css" />
  <h1>Welcome to My Awesome App</h1>
<div id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>
<div id="loader">Loading...</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved my question ty.

```
firebase.initializeApp({
 apiKey: '***',
 authDomain: // <--- I edit this->>>> '***.firebaseapp.com',
 projectId: '***'
});
```

just delete --> **https://**

Comment: In my case I had values in `process.env` stored between quotation marks. Removing quotation marks solved this issue.

Comment: if your environment variables contain comma please remove them and the error will be gone

Answer (score 0):

if your environment variables create files containing

1. semicolon(:)-Please remove and add equal(=)
2. no quotation
3. no comma. (quotation & comma)

please remove them and the hope error will be gone.

Comment: share code example